# Error when enabling access to postgresql data base engine via SQL cell magic

Tags: postgresql, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

```
%load_ext sql
%sql postgresql://test:test@localhost:5432/tm351test
```

Error message : (psycopg2.operationalError) connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL :role "test" does not exist

Im running jupyter notebook from anaconda

Comment: The error seems self-explanatory.  What is your question?

Comment: I want to run the cell correctly without errors

Comment: So create the role, or try to use a role which already exists.